# Failed to connect to TCP server on ESP32

Tags: networking, esp32, ip-address

I wrote a TCP client in C and a TCP server in Python. The client runs on a ESP32S2 board while the server runs on my PC (virtual Linux OS) and both the board and PC are connected to the same Wi-Fi. However, even though the same client code works as expected on my PC, it is not working when the code is loaded into the ESP32S2. The `connect()` function returns **errno 113**. I was wondering what could be the underlying issues.

Here is the client code (code handling Wi-Fi connection is omitted for simplicity):

```c
#define SERVER_IP   AF_INET           
#define SERVER_ADDR "192.168.1.157" 
#define SERVER_PORT 5566              

static int client_fd;

static void client_init(struct sockaddr_in addr) {
    client_fd = socket(SERVER_IP, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    addr.sin_family = SERVER_IP;
    addr.sin_port   = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    
    if (inet_pton(SERVER_IP, SERVER_ADDR, &(addr.sin_addr)) < 0) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Invalid address or protocol (errno: %d)", errno);
    }

    bzero(&(addr.sin_zero), 8);

    if (connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr *)(&addr), sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "connect error (errno: %d)", errno);
    }
}

void app_main() {
    wifi_sta_init();
    
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    client_init(server_addr);
}
```

Here is the server code:

```python
import socket
import sys

server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_addr = ('0.0.0.0', 5566)
server_sock.bind(server_addr)

server_sock.listen(1)

while True:
    print("waiting for a connection")
    connection, client_addr = server_sock.accept()

    try:
        print(f"connection from {client_addr}")

        while True:
            data = connection.recv(1024)

            with open('test.txt', 'wb') as file:
                file.write(data)

            print(f"received {data}")
            if data:
                break
            else:
                print("no more data from {client_address}")
                break
            
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Update:
The issue is resolved after I set the network adapter setting of the virtual machine to **bridged**.

Comment: Are you sure your Linux VM’s IP address is actually reachable from other devices? What’s the IP of your ESP32?

Comment: Hi @jcaron, I adjusted the network setting of my VM but the issue presists.

Comment: The IP of your server changed, I suppose? Did you update your client? Can you ping the client from your server? What are the addresses of both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is resolved after I set the network adapter of the virtual machine to **bridged**.